# If trait A[+T] extends B, should I be able to pass classes of type A[T] where B is needed?

Tags: scala

Here is the exact situation I am in (I do not want to simplify it for fear of missing out the cause of the error):

In the framework I am working in there is a

```
trait RequestHeader{...}
```

and another trait

```
trait Request[+A] extends RequestHeader{...}
```

There is a function that expects to receive an argument of type:

```
def f(arg: RequestHeader => Result) = {...}
```

I would expect to be able to pass in

```
arg': Request[AnyContent] => Result
```

However, this causes the compiler to complain. Why is this?

Comment: How is `Request[_]` related to this? You defined `Header[+A]` but have not shown any usage of it.

Comment: Mistyped, there is no Header[+A]. Edited now, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Function1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html) is contravariant in its input type, which makes sense if you think about it. Consider the following simpler example:

```
trait Foo
case object Bar extends Foo
case object Baz extends Foo

def f(g: Foo => Foo): Foo = g(Baz)
```

If I give `f` a function of type `Bar => Foo`, it's not going to be able to apply that to `Baz`. (A function of type `Foo => Bar`, on the other hand, would be perfectly fine.)